# Why does read(x) set -31073 to x instead of 99999 when entering 99999 in the terminal

Tags: input, types, integer, freepascal

This is a program written in Free Pascal:

```
program readTest;
var
    x: integer;
begin
    read(x);
    writeln(x)
end.
```

This is the execution script of this program:

```
$ echo 99999 | ./readTest
-31073
$
```

Why does `x` contain -31073 instead of 99999?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Free Pascal documentation:

> The integer type is an alias to the smallint type in the default Free Pascal mode. It is an alias for the longint type in either Delphi or ObjFPC mode.

> Smallint   -32768 .. 32767

99999 is out of valid range for x variable, that's why you got this "shifted" value.

Comment: So in short, add {$mode delphi} after the program line, or compile with -Sd